# How to create extendable controllers in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dot.js

I'm new to Node and I'm trying to create an MVC app with ExpressJS (http://expressjs.com/). I'm using the same folder structure as the MVC example (https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc) on GitHub.

In my controllers folder, I have 2 folders: main and system. What I'd like is to have a base controller defined in /controllers/system/index.js and have /controllers/main/index.js inherit the system controller. Every other module will extend system and override a few functions to generate a page.

In another tutorial I found the following code.

Base.js

```
var _ = require("underscore");
module.exports = {
    name: "base",
    extend: function(child) {
        return _.extend({}, this, child);
    },
    run: function(req, res, next) {

    }
};
```

Home.js

```
var BaseController = require("./Base"),
    View = require("../views/Base"),
    model = new (require("../models/ContentModel"));

module.exports = BaseController.extend({ 
    name: "Home",
    content: null,
    run: function(req, res, next) {
        model.setDB(req.db);
        var self = this;
        this.getContent(function() {
            var v = new View(res, 'home');
            v.render(self.content);
        })
    },
    getContent: function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        this.content = {};
        model.getlist(function(err, records) {
            if(records.length > 0) {
                self.content.bannerTitle = records[0].title;
                self.content.bannerText = records[0].text;
            }
            model.getlist(function(err, records) {
                var blogArticles = '';
                if(records.length > 0) {
                    var to = records.length < 5 ? records.length : 4;
                    for(var i=0; i<to; i++) {
                        var record = records[i];
                        blogArticles += '\
                            <div class="item">\
                                <img src="' + record.picture + '" alt="" />\
                                <a href="/blog/' + record.ID + '">' + record.title + '</a>\
                            </div>\
                        ';
                    }
                }
                self.content.blogArticles = blogArticles;
                callback();
            }, { type: 'blog' });
        }, { type: 'home' });
    }
});
```

How do you do this without Underscore's extend function? Does Express have a built in method to extend modules? I'm using doT.js for templating so I don't want to include another large library for one function.

Thanks!

Edit: Had to make a few changes to get the Base code from dc5 to work. System works but for main I'm getting this error on the inherits call:

```
util.js:555
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                          ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null
    at Function.create (native)
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:555:27)
```

/controllers/system/index.js:

```
var util = require( 'util' ),
    system = { };

system.index = function( req, res, next ) {
    res.render( 'main' );
};

module.exports = system;
```

/controllers/main/index.js:

```
var util = require( 'util' ),
    system = require( './../system/index' ),
    main = { };

util.inherits( main, system );

module.exports = main;
```

Comment: In this case, both system and main are simple objects.  Both arguments to `util.inherits` need to be constructors.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I tried putting main.constructor, main.prototype, and main.prototype.constructor and none of them worked?

Comment: system is initialized to {} which is an empty object of type `Object`.   I'll add an update to my answer that uses the same names and directory structure shortly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [util.inherits](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) for what you've described.  It isn't an replacement for `_.extend()`, but all that is needed for the example above is straight inheritance.

Usage: `util.inherits(constructor, superConstructor)`

base.js:

```
var util = require('util');

function Base() {…}

Base.prototype.run = function(req,res,next) {…}
module.exports = Base;
```

home.js:

```
var util = require('util');
var BaseController = require("./base");

function Home() {…}

util.inherits(home, BaseController);

Home.prototype.run = function(req,res,next) {…}
```

Or a standard JS inheritance pattern:

base.js:

```
function Base() {…}

Base.prototype.run = function(req,res,next) {…}
module.exports = Base;
```

home.js:

```
var BaseController = require("./base");

function Home() {
    BaseController.apply(this, arguments);
}

Home.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);
Home.prototype.run = function(req,res,next) {…}
```

---

From the updated samples in the question, the modules should look like this:

System:

```
var util = require('util');

function System() {
    this.txt  = "hello from ";
    this.name = "System"; 
}

System.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log(this.txt + this.name);
}

System.prototype.run = function(req,res,next) {
    this.sayHello();

    console.log('calling ==> overrideMe');
    this.overrideMe();

    console.log('calling ==> noOverride');
    this.noOverride();
    next ? next() : "";
}

System.prototype.overrideMe = function() {
    console.log('System.overrideMe');
}

System.prototype.noOverride = function() {
    console.log('System.noOverride');
}


module.exports = System;
```

Main:

```
var util = require('util');
var System = require("../system/");

function Main() {
    // Makes sure the System constructor is run
    System.apply(this, arguments);
    this.name = "Main"; 
}

util.inherits(Main, System);

Main.prototype.run = function(req,res,next) {
    this.sayHello();

    console.log('calling ==> overrideMe');
    this.overrideMe();

    console.log('calling ==> noOverride');
    this.noOverride();

    next ? next() : "";
}

Main.prototype.overrideMe = function() {
    console.log('Main.overrideMe');
}

module.exports = Main;
```

app.js in the root - a simplified express server:

```
var System  = require('./controllers/system');
var Main    = require('./controllers/main');
var express = require('express');
var path    = require('path');
var http    = require('http');
var app     = express();
var server;

var system = new System();
var main   = new Main();

app.configure(function() {
    "use strict";
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000, '127.0.0.1');
    app.use(system.run.bind(system));
    app.use(main.run.bind(main));
    app.use(app.router);
    //app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {redirect: false}));
    app.use(express.static(path.join("/Users/dave/personal/playground/yo"), {redirect: false}));
});


server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

From the browser access: `http://localhost:3000/`

Console output:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
hello from System
calling ==> overrideMe
System.overrideMe
calling ==> noOverride
System.noOverride
hello from Main
calling ==> overrideMe
Main.overrideMe
calling ==> noOverride
System.noOverride
```

**Important**

Because this example is using instances of `System` and `Main` to provide routes, the `run` method must be bound to the instance when passing it to express.  See: [MDN .bind documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the code and I'm getting this error: util.js:555
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                          ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, unfortunately I cannot get it to work. If in system I do module.exports = system (function not instanced) then in main I can do module.exports = new main( ) I don't get any errors but exported methods do not work with the dynamic routing in the MVC example I linked. If in system I create an instance (module.exports = new system()) that module will work as expected, but then when I try to extend it in main I get the same Object.create error. I can't seem to get extending to work and still have both controllers pass methods to module.exports? Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonathan I've update the example to work as a basic express app to show how to use the `run` method as a route in express.  The most important thing there is the use of `bind()` to provide the appropriate context when the `run` routes are called by express.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid complicated configuration and workarounds, use [ZinkyJS](https://zinkyjs.github.io/), it gives a better approach to make modules inheritance possible.